# How should I store shopping cart items in django session?

Tags: python, django

I know how to store cart objects in db using cart model but i don't understand how to save do such using session? how can i save clicked object in a session?

Comment: Please clarify what from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/, for example is not clear enough for you. It's just pretty detailed and contains what you need.

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov I am getting confused in where session is saving those datas server side or in db? i'm using request.session to store data and i want it to save in server side not in data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically if you wanna save objects in the user session you can use this line of code:

```
request.session['item'] = data
```

If you want to delete it :

```
del request.session['item']
```

Comment: how to set sessionid? then